# Why aren't the usernames getting linked correctly?

Tags: bug, status-completed

Regarding: https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1015/why-is-describe-a-process-of-communication-non-real-question

And this question: [Why is "describe a process of communication" non real question?](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1014/why-is-describe-a-process-of-communication-non-real-question)

One appears to be migrated from meta.so and also a merge occurred. Now it looks like the usernames aren't being linked correctly. At least one user has confirmed that his accounts are linked, so I suspect this is a bug related to migrating and merging.

Comment: I really don't understand all this account nonsense on this site. Once you sign up and create a profile, it's not intuitive at all that this doesn't work accross the whole site. It seems pointless and is definitely annoying to have to create separate "accounts" for all the Stack Exchange forums or whatever they are called. I'm on EE and Photography, but occasionally have browsed other topics. I've tried to leave comments or answers but the system wants you to log in again even though it already knows who I am. I think to myself *"screw this"* and leave. This system stifles participation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer to the question (which is a developer problem, there's nothing I can do about it) but I'll explain what happened:

1. The question was posted on Meta.Electronics, and got no answers for a while because I was in lab.
2. 20 minutes later, it was cross-posted on Meta.Stackoverflow, where it got an answer from [ChrisF](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf).
3. Half an hour later, the post on Meta.Stackoverflow with the answer from ChrisF was migrated from to Meta.Electronics.  [ChrisF](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5957/chrisf), [xralf](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/8407/xralf), and [Pekka](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/8416/pekka) all have user accounts on Meta.Electronics, but *no usernames were associated.*  [Bobby](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/136489/bobby?tab=accounts) does not have an account, so [his comment](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1014/why-is-describe-a-process-of-communication-non-real-question#comment2341_1014) does not have an owner.
4. I noticed the lack of association and duplication of the question, so I closed the question from Meta.SO as a dupe of the earlier question.  The earlier question had an associated username.
5. I merged the migrated question with the earlier question, which moved ChrisF's answer over to the earlier question, so at least part of the post had an association.

The problem was also noted in the [comments to ChrisF's answer](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1014/why-is-describe-a-process-of-communication-non-real-question#comment2352_1016) and in a top-secret chatroom, message ID 3640824.